# Anyone interested in mini web platform for latex/markdown?

Tags: latex, web

(I apologize in advance since this is not strictly Mathematica-related, but this still seems potentially relevant to audience. Feel free to remove or refile.)

So I got sick of keeping all my notes spread across Mathematica notebooks, and wrote a tiny website platform to let me do my math musings and easily share things. Basically, I wanted something that let me quickly and easily jot down stuff with markdown and latex.

I've been using it for months and it's great for me, but I have no idea whether anyone else would be interested in this sort of thing... but if anyone would be, it'd be you lot. So if you want, see it / try it / use it at http://stacked.by.tc.

If there is interest, maybe I'll try to polish it up some and release it into the wild as open source. If there's not, that's fine too, less work for me.

Incidentally, I decided to sit down and write this after completely failing to come up with an adequate path for exporting Mathematica work to the web. None of the options quite worked out for me, but perhaps it was just me.

Comment: Looks pretty cool!

Comment: How do you actually use it to create content? I made an account, and can create a post, but it is commingled with yours. Is it how it is meant to be?

Comment: I've only really used it myself, the multi-user part hasn't been looked at in months. But yeah, I should probably turn it off by default. For now, you can type `-pub` or `-@trev` into the grep bar and it'll hide all my junk.

Comment: This is great work! Unfortunately, it has nothing to do with Mathematica which makes it clearly off-topic. You could post about it in the site chat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it is unrelated to Mathematica and is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate MD with Wolfram Language and eventually publish your documents+code (in/out) +graphics the ultimate solution is a Jupyter kernel for the Wolfram Language like the official one or  JWLS / JWLS_2 .

Comment: Thanks for the note. I had Jupyter set up a couple years back and liked it, but as I recall it worked with SageMath, I didn't know there was one for Wolfram...

Comment: Yes these kernels are relatively recent and still in development, but they very usable.